# Получение компонентов(поля текста) префаба во время Instantiate'а

Tags: c#, unity3d

Программа парсит sql таблицы и по количеству строк в sql, в сцене создаются префабы которые должны иметь в себе записи из этих таблиц, но появилась трудность с присвоением спарсиных значений строкам префаба. Изначально префаба в сцене нет(спаунится после нажатия кнопки) и я не вижу в инспекторе его компоненты которые бы мог перетащить в скрипт. Пытался залочить замком инспектор с открытым скриптом и пытался перетащить компоненты префаба, но Unity не позволила перетащить!

[image: Строки куда нужно перетащить компоненты префаба]
[image: Компоненты-строчки префаба]

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Runtime;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class GetProd : MonoBehaviour
{
    public JSONObject JO;
    public string GetTypePatch;
    public WWW wwwPeod;
    public RectTransform prefab; //кладем ItemPrefab в инспекторе
    public RectTransform content;
    private GameObject Content;
    [SerializeField] private Button add_button;
    [SerializeField] private Text name;
    [SerializeField] private Text type;
    [SerializeField] private Text calories;
    [SerializeField] private Text price;
    [SerializeField] private Text account;
    [SerializeField] private Text date;


    void Awake()
    {
        add_button.onClick.AddListener(() => { View(); });
    }

    void Start()
    {
        wwwPeod = new WWW(GetTypePatch);
    }
    void Update()
    {
        if (wwwPeod != null && wwwPeod.isDone)
        {
            if (wwwPeod.error == null)
            {
                JO = new JSONObject(wwwPeod.text);
                wwwPeod = null;
            }
            else { print(wwwPeod.error); }
        }
    }

    void View()
    {

        if (JO != null)
        {
            foreach (var json in JO.list)
            {
                var data = json.ToDictionary();
                name.text = " Название продукта: " + data["product_name"]; //парсится с хостинга
                type.text = " Тип продукта: " + data["type_id"]; //парсится с хостинга
                calories.text = " Калорийность: " + data["product_calories"]; //парсится с хостинга
                price.text = " Цена: " + data["product_price"]; //парсится с хостинга
                account.text = " Счёт: " + data["account_id"]; //парсится с хостинга
                date.text = " Дата: " + data["expenses_date"]; //парсится с хостинга
                var instance = GameObject.Instantiate(prefab.gameObject) as GameObject;
                instance.transform.SetParent(content, false);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Префабы спаунятся относительно компонента скролл листа -> content!
Если есть идеи как можно иначе спаунить префабы с нужными мне записями на нем, то готов выслушать предложения.
Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Сослаться внутри префаба на оъект сцены не получится, ссылку из префаба можно сделать только на другой префаб, т.к. префабы ничего не знают о сцене, они ссылаются  ресурсы.

При старте можно [найти](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.Find.html) объект по имени:

```
 GameObject.Find("one");
```

однако это поиск по всей сцене, и если Вас это не устраивает тогда можно перебрать всех потомков, проверяя их имена:

```
for (var child : Transform in transform) {
    if(child.gameObject.name == "one")
    {
        // присвоить что надо куда надо
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

В основном скрипте я ничего не стал присваивать префабу а все что приходит с хостинга я записываю в переменные которые тут же парсятся новым скриптом повешенным на префабе, то есть новый скрипт на префабе, как только спаунится префаб, парсит значения с переменных основного скрипта.

P.S. В "Content" спаунятся все префабы!

Основной скрипт

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Runtime;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class GetProd : MonoBehaviour
{
    public JSONObject JO;
    public string GetTypePatch;
    public WWW wwwPeod;
    public RectTransform prefab; //кладем ItemPrefab в инспекторе
    public RectTransform content;
    [SerializeField] private Button add_button;
    [HideInInspector] public string prod_name;
    [HideInInspector] public string prod_type;
    [HideInInspector] public string prod_calories;
    [HideInInspector] public string prod_account;
    [HideInInspector] public string prod_price;
    [HideInInspector] public string prod_date;

    void Awake()
    {
        add_button.onClick.AddListener(() => { View(); });
    }

    void Start()
    {
        wwwPeod = new WWW(GetTypePatch);
    }
    void Update()
    {
        if (wwwPeod != null && wwwPeod.isDone)
        {
            if (wwwPeod.error == null)
            {
                JO = new JSONObject(wwwPeod.text);
                wwwPeod = null;
            }
            else { print(wwwPeod.error); }
        }
    }

    void View()
    {
        if (JO != null)
        {

            foreach (var json in JO.list)
            {
                var data = json.ToDictionary();
                prod_name = data["product_name"];
                prod_type = data["type_id"];
                prod_calories = data["product_calories"];
                prod_price = data["product_price"];
                prod_account = data["account_id"];
                prod_date = data["expenses_date"];
                var instance = GameObject.Instantiate(prefab.gameObject) as GameObject;
                instance.transform.SetParent(content, false); 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Скрипт повешенный на префабе

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Pref : MonoBehaviour
{
    private GameObject Content;
    [SerializeField] private Text prod_name;
    [SerializeField] private Text prod_type;
    [SerializeField] private Text prod_calories;
    [SerializeField] private Text prod_price;
    [SerializeField] private Text prod_account;
    [SerializeField] private Text prod_date;
    private void Awake()
    {
        Content = GameObject.Find("Content");
        prod_name.text = Content.GetComponent<GetProd>().prod_name;
        prod_type.text = Content.GetComponent<GetProd>().prod_type;
        prod_calories.text = Content.GetComponent<GetProd>().prod_calories;
        prod_price.text = Content.GetComponent<GetProd>().prod_price;
        prod_account.text = Content.GetComponent<GetProd>().prod_account;
        prod_date.text = Content.GetComponent<GetProd>().prod_date;
    }

}
```